# ASP.Net Pagemethod is Not Calling Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webmethod

Relevant Code:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
    </asp:ScriptReference>
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
    </asp:ScriptReference>
    <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
    </asp:ScriptReference>
  </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
```

**js**

```
function GetPhaseCodes(sender, eventArgs) {
  var JN = document.getElementById("JobNumber");
  if (JN.Value != -1 && JN.Value != null) {
    PageMethods.JobNumSelected(sender, JN.Value, onSucess, onError)

  }
}

function onSucess(result) {
  alert(result);
}

function onError(result) {
  alert('Cannot process your request at the moment, please try later.');
}
```

C-Sharp

```
[WebMethod]
public static string JobNumSelected(RadDropDownList e, string JobNumb) {
  //Do Stuff
}
```

I'm programming this in Visual Studio 2008. I can put a breakpoint in the JS code and see that it gets to the function call. However once I start stepping through the function call I go to this "blank [dynamic]" file (for a lack of a better word) where I can step through essentially endlessly without ever getting to the code in JobNumSelected. I do not get any error messages, and I cannot simply continue the program to a breakpoints in JobNumSelected.

Comment: Sounds like what you want to do is set a breakpoint in JobNumSelected, to see if it's being hit.  You already say you can get to the JS function call, so this would be the next step.

Comment: I've put breakpoints in JobNumSelected with the code above it would not hit it. I've been able to get to it sometimes during my tweaking the issue seems to be around what can be passed and returned using pagemethods. Removing RadDropDownList and onSuccess/onError will result in JobNumSelected being hit. However, I need to access the RadDropDownList in the function to perform the action I wanted to.

Comment: I would imagine it's a problem passing a client object RadDropDownList to the server and expecting it to become a server side RadDropDownList.  Are you working off an example that does this successfully?  If you need this to work for many different drop downs, I'd try passing the ID of the control (as a string), and then do a Page.FindControl() in the method using the ID passed.